# Exercise 2.18 Brezis' Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces and let $ A:D(A)\subset E \rightarrow F$ be a densely defined unbounded operator.

(1) Prove that $N(A')=R(A)^{\bot}$ and $N(A)\subset R(A')^{\bot}$.

(2) Let's assume A is closed, prove that $N(A)=R(A')^{\bot}$.

I have already proved (1) and I am trying to prove (2) with the Hahn-Banach theorem.

By contradiction: if $\bar{u}\in R(A')^{\bot}$ such that $[\bar{u},0]\not\in G(A)$ ( $G(A)$ is the graph of A) there exists a function $f$ and some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that: $f([u,Au])<\alpha<f([\bar{u},0])$     $\forall u\in D(A)$ . Cause $G(A)$ is a linear space $f([u,Au])=0$ $\forall [u,Au] \in G(A)$, so $f(\bar{u},0)>0$. Is there a way to find a contradiction saying $f(\bar{u},0)$ should be equal to $0$?
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you know the theorem that says: *$A$ is closable if and only  if $D(A')$ is dense*?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually not, it should be explained in Chapter 3, but this is a problem of the Chapter 2. Could it help to solve the problem?

Comment: Forget it. I got an easier answer below which doesn't use this.

Comment: @amsmath How did you prove item (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u\in R(A')^\perp$ means that for every $y'\in D(A')$ and every sequence $(u_n)\subset D(A)$ with $u_n\to u$ we have $y'(Au_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Now, as you started, if $(u,0)\notin G(A)$, then there exists a bounded linear functional $f$ on $E\times F$ such that $f(x,Ax) = 0$ for all $x\in D(A)$ and $f(u,0) = 1$. Now, define the functional $y' : F\to\Bbb K$ by $y'(y) := f(0,y)$. Then, obviously, $y'\in F'$. But also for $x\in D(A)$ we have
$$
|y'(Ax)| = |f(0,Ax)| = |f(x,Ax)-f(x,0)| = |f(x,0)|\le \|f\|\|x\|.
$$
That is, $y'\in D(A')$.

So, if $(u_n)\subset D(A)$ is a sequence with $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n = u$, then
\begin{align*}
0
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}y'(Au_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(0,Au_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(u_n,Au_n)-f(u_n,0)\\
&= -\lim_{n\to\infty}f(u_n,0) = -f(u,0) = -1,
\end{align*}
a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, but I have some doubts. Are the first lines right because $y' \in D(A')$ then for every $u \in D(A)$ the composition $y'(Au)$ is continuous (bounded) in $u$? Then, when you say $y':F\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ what do you mean by $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: First question: Yes, exactly. Second question: $\Bbb K$ is either $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. Choose your favorite field. ;-)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @Djenta how did you prove (1)?

Comment: $y'\in N(A')\,\Longleftrightarrow\, A'y'=0\,\Longleftrightarrow\,(A'y')x=0\,\forall x\in E\,\Longleftrightarrow\,y'(Ax)=0\,\forall x\in E\,\Longleftrightarrow\,y'(y)=0\,\forall y\in R(A)\,\Longleftrightarrow\,y'\in R(A)^\perp$.

Comment: @amsmath Thank you very much!